# Why "Be quiet!" may sound as "Be quiets!"

Tags: adjectives, pronunciation, listening

I guess "(Everyone) Be quiet!" referring to a group of people is correct.

But it may sound as "Be quiet**s**!" when they yell. Is it correct?

Comment: "Quiets" is not correct either.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: .......Simples.

Comment: When people shout in English you may hear some *lenition* of word final /t/. This means it will sound more like an /s/. You may have heard people shouting "Quiet" very forcefully so that it sounded like "Quiets"!

Comment: That's not lenition, that's aspiration. Lenition would be t -> d -> z/th. In AmE a word final t is unaspirated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not correct.

*Quiet* in "Be quiet" is an adjective. Adjectives in English are not inflected for number, and the same word is used whether or not it's describing [addressed to, here] one person or more than one.

Comment: "Quiets!" is not correct. I'll update my answer in a bit.

Comment: I heard "Quiets!" on a movie: http://youtu.be/CIeg78e3JQk?t=28s

Comment: @Josep: You're just mishearing - the teacher says *"**Quiet!**"* there, as one would expect.

Comment: You're right, it's just a strong T sound. Thank you both!